# Почему чтобы использовать суперглобальный массив $_COOKIE недостаточно только функции setcookie()?

Tags: php, cookie

Допустим нужно задать cookie page_visit:

```
setcookie("page_visit", 1, time() + 5);
```

**Почему не получается после задания cookie использовать массив $_COOKIE?**


Если попробовать обратиться к $_COOKIE["page_visit"], то выдаст ошибку Undefined index: page_visit.
**Почему приходится вручную задавать значение элементу массива $_COOKIE?**

```
$_COOKIE["page_visit"] = 1;
```

Comment: Потому что запрос и ответ это никак не связанные вещи. После setcookie в браузер отправится соответствующий заголовок, браузер его запомнит, при следующем запросе заполнит HTTP-заголовок куками и только после этого $_COOKIE будет уже заполнен во втором запросе. А до этого в $_COOKIE содержатся только куки из первого запроса, в котором новых кук нет и не должно быть

Answer (score 0):

А вообще в примере у вас кука просто самоуничтожается, вам нужно прописать хотя больше, допустим time() + 3600

```
<?php
session_start();
setCookie('start', 'ok', time() + 3600);
echo $_COOKIE['start'];
```

Comment: Показанный вами код не работает и тоже выводит пустоту.

Comment: Обновите страницу и будет

Comment: @uberchel не нужно инициализировать сессию для работы с cookies.

Comment: Блин, что то сглупил дак сглупил, видать уже сплю )

Answer (score 0):

Суперглобальный массив `$_COOKIES` хранит ассоциативный массив (array) значений, переданных скрипту через `HTTP Cookies`: [документация](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.cookies)

метод `setcookie()` - задает cookie, которое будет передано клиенту вместе с другими HTTP-заголовками.

Соответственно, при установке куков вы отправляете браузеру заголовок, и браузер сохряняет куку себе. При последующем запросе браузер отправит серверу эту куку, и теперь она будет доступна в `$_COOKIES`.